# Is there any significance to including the company name in the platform triplet?

Tags: c++, clang

On Ubuntu, `clang++ --version` says the platform triplet is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`, and I expected to see the same string on all x86_64 distrbutions.

Yet on Fedora, `clang++ --version` prints `x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu`.

Does `redhat` vs `pc` have any significance? (Perhaps including the company name implies the compiler is configured in an unusual way?)

Or is this just an arbitrary string?

Comment: Seems the triplet is a bit tricky. https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet

Comment: Quoting from the link in Eljay's comment, _"Notice how the vendor field is mostly irrelevant and is usually 'pc' for 32-bit x86 systems or 'unknown' or 'none' for other systems...since the vendor field is mostly unused, the GNU build system allows you to leave out the vendor field"_

Comment: Hmm, so this implies: A - Fedora is the outlier, not Ubuntu, and B - it's probably just an unused string.

Comment: For various historical reasons, RedHat has always been an odd case. They even shipped compilers that [never really existed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22080), and often include RedHat specific compiler builds to deal with build process quirks, especially in relation to the kernel.

Comment: @tadman Interesting. Can you elaborate on the "process quirks"?

Comment: Building the kernel has not always been a straight-forward process, especially when Fedora/RedHat is trying to switch the default compiler out. As such, they sometimes needed to include a kernel-specific compiler, or one with patches to accommodate code they've yet to update to new standards, etc. If you're curious, there are surely innumerable esoteric bug reports justifying these decisions.